# Is it possible to create a standalone executable with net-core?

Tags: windows, .net-core

When I run the command:

```
dotnet build -c Release
```

I get the program and necessary dlls of my project, however for the program to work on another computer I have to install computer to computer the **.NET Core Runtime**:

- https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/current/runtime

Would it be possible to create a standalone program for Windows?

Comment: Have you tried the `dotnet publish` command?

Comment: @DavidG Unfortunately it does not work for this, it still has the error: "A fatal error occurred. The required library hostfxr.dll could not be found."... After I tried recompile with `--self-contained`, but i get: `error NETSDK1031: It is not supported to build or publish a self-contained application without specifying a RuntimeIdentifier. Please either specify a RuntimeIdentifier or set SelfContained to false.`. I'm sure I forgot something and it's my fault, but at the moment I admit I'm lost.

Comment: So, er, maybe you should, er, specify a runtime identifier? There is a `-r` command...

Comment: @DavidG I'm testing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#runtimeidentifiers

Comment: @DavidG -r param and `<RuntimeIdentifier>` working fine. Unfortunately we sent a lot of DLLs, we created all these needs, but now it weighs 68MB in total. Maybe it's a bad thing about modern applications, including Qt too (this one that makes me suffer so much from the weight of "release applications")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a self-contained executable, you should use `dotnet publish`. For example:

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c release
```

If you are using .NET Core 3, you can also trim a lot of these libraries out by adding the [`PublishTrimmed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#assembly-linking) property to your csproj file, for example:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Provided your app doesn't call any of the framework libraries using reflection (i.e. the dotnet command is unable to figure out you need one of the libraries it trims out), your output will be much smaller.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks! :)